# How can I read/write local variables dynamically in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am pretty new to angular and was wondering how I can access a **LOCAL** variable dynamically. Here is the scenario I am facing :

I am declaring 7 objects **within** an IF statement :

```js
if (...) {
   const day1 = { date: null, total: 0 };
   const day2 = { date: null, total: 0 };
   const day3 = { date: null, total: 0 };
   const day4 = { date: null, total: 0 };
   const day5 = { date: null, total: 0 };
   const day6 = { date: null, total: 0 };
   const day7 = { date: null, total: 0 };
}
```

Later within that IF statement, I need to assign a value to the "total" key depending on calculations also done within that IF statement.

Now, instead of doing something like this later within the IF statement :

```js
day1.date = ... ;
day2.date = ... ;
day3.date = ... ;
day4.date = ... ;
day5.date = ... ;
day6.date = ... ;
day7.date = ... ;
```

I would like to do something like this to keep my code neat and efficient (obviously, this does not work) :

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  ['day' + i].date = ... ;
}
```

It would have worked if the 7 objects were declared globally and then using `this['day' + i].date`. But the objects being declared locally in the IF statement, I can't use this syntax.

**My questions are the following :**

1. Is there something similar for locally declared variables?
2. Even better, can I declare these 7 local objects dynamically in a for loop?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: This isn't an Angular question, it is a JavaScript / TypeScript question.

Comment: Why not use an array to represent days instead of individual variables?

Comment: Why don't you use an array of 7 objects so you can access in the for loop through the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Best solution: Use an array instead:

Change this:

```
if (...) {
    const day1 = { date: null, total: 0 };
    const day2 = { date: null, total: 0 };
    const day3 = { date: null, total: 0 };
    const day4 = { date: null, total: 0 };
    const day5 = { date: null, total: 0 };
    const day6 = { date: null, total: 0 };
    const day7 = { date: null, total: 0 };

   // ...

    day1.date = ... ;
    day2.date = ... ;
    day3.date = ... ;
    day4.date = ... ;
    day5.date = ... ;
    day6.date = ... ;
    day7.date = ... ;
}
```

...to this:

```
// Declared in module scope:
type Day = { date: Date | null, total: number };

// Inside your function:
if( ... ) {
    
    const days: Day[] = [
        { date: null, total: 0 },
        { date: null, total: 0 },
        { date: null, total: 0 },
        { date: null, total: 0 },
        { date: null, total: 0 },
        { date: null, total: 0 },
        { date: null, total: 0 }
    ];
    
    //

    for( let i = 0; i < 7; i++ ) {
      days[i].date = ...
    }
}
```

You can also initialize `days` in a loop too:

```
const days: Day[] = [];
for( let i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
{
    days[i] = { date: null, total: 0 };
}
```

And you can have named references to elements in the array if you want to keep on using `day1`, `day2`, etc (but remember these are references to the object **values** in the array rather than being aliases to array indexes):

```
const day1 = days[0];
const day2 = days[1];
```

...though try not to let your 1-based day numbering be confused with JavaScript/TypeScript's 0-based array indexing.

### Worst solution: Using `eval`:

You can manipulate locals using `eval()`, but you shouldn't use `eval()`, **ever**. But you can do this:

```
if (...) {
    const day1 = { date: null, total: 0 };
    const day2 = { date: null, total: 0 };
    const day3 = { date: null, total: 0 };
    const day4 = { date: null, total: 0 };
    const day5 = { date: null, total: 0 };
    const day6 = { date: null, total: 0 };
    const day7 = { date: null, total: 0 };

    for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        const expr = 'day' + i + ' = ...;';
        console.log( expr );
        eval( expr );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Indeed, it seems as thought the use of an array is the best solution for this scenario. I'd like to mark this as the accepted answer. However, I'd simply like to know if such a thing equivalent to `this['day' + i]` exists for locally declared variables. Thank you

Comment: @RemyA. No, no such thing exists for local variables. The only reason that you can do that with (**only**) global-scope variables is because global-scope variables are also JavaScript object properties in the `global` object (in web-browsers this is the `window` object). Note that you can access a function's parameter arguments using the implicit `arguments` array-like object, but this is not recommended - and what you're asking is a bad idea in TypeScript anyway because it would be impossible to statically-type a `locals['day'+i]` expression.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you so much for you help and for the clear explanation.